# Safe Variable VAC Power Supply using Switch

Tags: power-supply, switches, transformer, mains, safety

I want to make a variable VAC power supply, maybe using 3-5A transformer. I provide the simple circuit diagram below.

[image: 220 VAC to Variable VAC]

What should I add to ensure its safety? Thank you.

Comment: How about a fuse?

Comment: Fuses on both sides. Switch to be break before make to prevent shorting the windings during switching.